# When I pass a variable into a private method in golang, does it create a new instance?

Tags: pointers, variables, go

If I have main function:

```
var a = "foo"
modify(a)
fmt.Println(a)
```

where

```
func modify(s string) error {
  s = "bar"
}
```

will the result be `"foo"` or `"bar"`?

Comment: What was the result of your test?

Comment: Kinda seems like a homework question. Have you tested it?

Comment: Exported functions don't operate any differently than non-exported.

Comment: You have all the code necessary to find the answer, why not just run it and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. It won't compile because neither `'foo'` nor `'bar'` is a single character. But let's say you used double quotes instead.

In Golang, arguments are passed by value (they are copied to the new place in memory - stack or heap), and it does not matter whether it is a private or a public method or arbitrary function. The new instance is modified. The result of your example will be `"foo"`.

In order to modify variable lying outside of the function, you have to explicitly pass the pointer pointing to such variable.

```
func modify(s *string) {
  *s = "bar"
}

...

var a = "foo"
modify(&a)
println(a) // will print "bar"
```

In this case pointer itself is passed by values (it is copied) but its value (the address of `a`) still points to the same variable. So the `a` can by modified through the pointer.